# how to convert json into long format table in postgresql/plpgsql?

Tags: json, postgresql, plpgsql, longtable

first of all apology for using image. however I can't seem to post my question as it seems I have issue in the formatting so I can't post my question, but I can't figure out whats wrong..

I have table like this
[table source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtHk7.png)

I would like to convert it to be structured like below

| user_id | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user_1 | a | 3 |
| user_1 | b | 1 |
| user_1 | c | 3 |
| user_2 | c | 2 |
| user_2 | e | 1 |
| user_3 | a | 1 |
| user_3 | f | 2 |

I used query below currently. but it has limit based on listed wtl_key a to e, whereas I can't list all the possible key as I don't know all the possible key. I want to query to catch all json key which could be aa,bb,zz, etc

```
with wide_to_long_key AS (
select unnest(array['a','b','c','d','e']) as wtl_key
)
, data AS (
select
 user_id
 ,details::json->'a' as a
 ,details::json->'b' as b
 ,details::json->'c' as c
 ,details::json->'d' as d
 ,details::json->'e' as e
)
select
 user_id
 ,wtl_key
 ,case
   when wtl_key='a' THEN a
   when wtl_key='b' THEN b
   when wtl_key='c' THEN c
   when wtl_key='d' THEN d
   when wtl_key='e' THEN e
   when wtl_key='a' THEN a
   end as value
from
 data
CROSS JOIN
 wide_to_long_key
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If type of **details** column is json you can use `json_each_text` or if is jsonb you can use `jsonb_each_text`

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=f9a8656dafc89ea8e314983f2f8fe49f)

```sql
select
  t.user_id,
  e.*
from
  test t
  cross join json_each_text(t.details) e
```

Comment: This works. thanks a lot